# Getting Twilio.Device client error {message: "Cannot register. Token not validated", code: 31204} intermittently during resetup

Tags: client, device, twilio, twilio-php

I am getting `Twilio.Device` client error

```
{message: "Cannot register. Token not validated", code: 31204}
```

intermittently during resetup of `Twilio.Device`.

Can any one tell me what this error implies?

Since I am generating the token correctly, but I think twilio websocket was not able to validate it due to some reason.

Should I try to resetup using the same token or should I generate a new one?

Thanks.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. Are you able to successfully register on other occasions? Could you share the code you are using to generate the token?

Comment: yes I am able to register on other occasions

Comment: $token = new Services_Twilio_Capability($account_sid, $auth_token);
$token->allowClientOutgoing($app_id);
$token->allowClientIncoming($client_name);
echo $token->generateToken(1800);

Comment: Do you generate a new token for each page load?

Comment: yes once on page load and 5 mins before expiry time through ajax

Comment: I would get in touch with help@twilio.com and send them all this information. They'll likely be able to help you more now.

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: Facing the same issue here @philnash, do you have any updates?

Comment: I saw the same error today, I have no idea what caused it

Comment: I heard something recently about clock drift and the `nbf` ("not before") attribute of the JWT header being late and causing the access token to be rejected. Can you check that any tokens that fail (you can do so with https://jwt.io), see what the `nbf` attribute says and check if the token is indeed not yet valid.